# How to sync AlarmManager with system time?

Tags: android, widget, alarmmanager, broadcast

I have a question, I'm using an AlarManager to update a Widget every minute (it's a clock) to display the current time, however, the AlarmManager is never synced with the System clock in the device, I use this:

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, System.getCurrentTimeInMillis(), 60000, pendingIntent);
```

It works every minute, however, the problem is that, If I put the widget in the screen at 2:15:30 pm for example, one minute after that its the time the AlarmManager is going to call the broadcast again, so the next update will be at 2:16:30 pm, and it won't be synced with the system time because when the system time displays 2:16:00pm the widget will still show up 2:15:00pm.

I hope I was clear enough, I would appreciate your help, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument to setRepeating is the time you want the alarm to fire the first time.  You need to do the arithmetic to align it to the next minute boundary.  For example something like:

```
 now = system.getCurrentTimeInMillis();
 oneMinuteFromNow = now  + oneMinute;
 nextMinuteRollover = oneMinuteFromNow - (oneMinuteFromNow % oneMinute);
```

then use nextMinuteRollover as the second argument to setRepeating.

(this could obviously be simplified -- I made it verbose so you could see what the code was doing.)

Comment: `now = system.getCurrentTimeInMillis();  oneMinuteFromNow = now + 60000;  nextMinuteRollover = oneMinuteFromNow - (oneMinuteFromNow % 60000);`  I understand that, if the current time is 2:15:30 pm, oneMinuteFromNow will be the same time plus 1 minute, so it's the same problem, because it will start in a non exact minute; I will give it a try but this is my initial assumption. Thank you!

Comment: but when you subtract off oneMinuteFromNow mod oneMinute it aligns nextMinuteRollover with the clock.

Comment: In your example, one minute from now will be 2:16:30.   oneMinuteFromNow mod oneMinute will be 30 seconds so nextMinuteRollover will be 2:16:00  (exactly)

Comment: I will give it a try asap and let you know my results, I hope it works, I'm currently using the AlarmManager to update a widget every second, but it consumes a lot of battery, I'd prefer to update it every minute exactly, thanks!

Comment: Ok, I think I got it, the resulting line would be as follow: `alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, nextMinuteRollover, 60000, test(context));` for example if I have 3:30:15pm `nextMinuteRollover` gives me 3:31:00pm sharp, so I start it at the next minute, and then I set the repeat each 60000 millis. If I would use `NextMinuteRollover` the `AlarmManager` would repeat itself every milliseconds that forms 3:31:00pm which did not work. Anyway, you gave me the 95% of the solution, thanks a lot!!